# Php Error syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, syntax

I've created code in php
which is below

```
<?php

$text = $_POST["text"];
$name = $_POST["name"];

$Voice = new COM("SAPI.SpVoice");   

$FileStream = new COM("SAPI.SpFileStream"); 

$FileStream->Open("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\1\\"$name"", 3, false); 
$Voice->AllowAudioOutputFormatChangesOnNextSet = false; 

$Voice->AudioOutputStream = $FileStream; 

$Voice->Speak($text);
$FileStream->Close();

?>
```

But It gives error  `syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE)` 
how can it be solved?

Comment: try  using .$name and remove "" after $name

Comment: ^ Two too many. Should be `$FileStream->Open("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\1\\$name", 3, false); `

Comment: Thank you friend resolve the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ", you can just write

`"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\1\\$name"`

Alternatively:

`"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\1\\{$name}"`

Otherwise:

`"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\1\\" . $name`

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
$FileStream->Open("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\1\\"$name"", 3, false);
```

It should be

```
$FileStream->Open("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\1\\".$name, 3, false);
```